# Selective datatable creation within flexmarkdown

Tags: shiny, interactive, dt, flexdashboard

I am trying to build a selector for a `datatable` object in my `flexmarkdown` sheet.

So this is my current (example) layout and I'm trying to build a reactive selector that takes the mineral type input on the left side and then re-renders 
the entire table to only select for "Rock Type = Type 1" in this case.

Full source @pastebin here: [Link](http://pastebin.com/ETb0SkmA)

My current selector:

````
```{r}
selectInput("input_type","Mineral Type:", data$`Rock Type`)

```
````

I'm been able to achieve this by doing the below but I'd also like to build in a selection for all/no groupings.

````
```{r}
dataInput <- reactive({
  subset(data,data$`Rock Type` == input$input_type)
  })

renderDataTable(dataInput())
```
````

[image: Current Layout]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an **All** option to your selectInput, that you check in the reactive:

````
```{r}
selectInput("input_type","Mineral Type:", c("All", unique(data$`Rock Type`))
```

```{r}
dataInput <- reactive({
  if(input$input_type=="All")
    data
  else
    subset(data,`Rock Type` == input$input_type)
  })

renderDataTable(dataInput())
```
````